# How to generate k-itemset for apriori alogrithm?

Tags: c#, data-mining, apriori

I have written this code to generate itemsets of two.

I'm writing `list<list<>>` list of list to generate item sets of two, and want to optimize the code to generate itemsets of length k.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

namespace HW3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int Min_support = 360;
        private static List<String> itemSet = new List<string>();
        private static List<List<String>> C_itemSet = new List<List<string>>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List_Movies();
            //for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++)
            //{ }
            C_itemSet = Geneate_Sets(itemSet);

            for (int i = 0; i < C_itemSet.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < C_itemSet[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(C_itemSet.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(j));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void List_Movies()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=.;AttachDbFilename=D:\DBs\MovieClick.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
            OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            myConn.Open();
            string str = "select Movie,COUNT(Movie) from Movies group by Movie HAVING COUNT(MOVIE) > "+Min_support;
            OleDbCommand myComm = new OleDbCommand(str, myConn);
            OleDbDataReader DR = myComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                if (DR[0] != null)
                    itemSet.Add(DR[0].ToString()); // Movie name
            }

            myConn.Close();
        }

        private static List<List<String>> Geneate_Sets(List<String> fSet )
        {
            List<List<String>> finalSet= new List<List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fSet.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < fSet.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (!fSet[i].Equals(fSet[j]))
                    {
                        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                        temp.Add(fSet[i]);
                        temp.Add(fSet[j]);

                            finalSet.Add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            return finalSet;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [implementing apriori in c# with sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748302/implementing-apriori-in-c-sharp-with-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your data is really really huge, I suggest you just load it into a good library that already has Apriori implemented right.

Because judging from your code, you are really *far* from an Apriori implementation, in particular of one that actually performs well, sorry. As is, **you don't seem to have anything of APRIORI yet**. Don't expect us to write the algorithm for you.